# Visual Studio Code: Incremental numbers at different position in hex and other forms

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for a method where I place cursors at different positions, and then place numbers at those positions in hex form such that numbers are ranging from 8 to 10, in two digit format, as following:

```
case_
case_
case_
case_
case_
case_
case_
case_
case_
```

into :

```
case_08
case_09
case_0A
case_0B
case_0C
case_0D
case_0E
case_0F
case_10
```

Another example series:

```
case_12
case_16
case_20
case_24
case_28
case_32
case_36
case_40
```

Anyone knows any key(combination) to do that?

Comment: So I tried ctrl+shift+p and then "increment multiple selected numbers". But this only increment from 1 to onwards.

Comment: Do you want to be able to make any number of selections, say 12, and have the hex numbers start over after `10`?  So the 10th selection would be `08`?

Comment: I want any series of number in any radix starting from any digital in any number of digits.

Comment: I used `${matchIndex} % 9 + 8` where the `8` is the starting point `08` and the `9` makes it "wrap".  You should give an example in the question if there was other behaviour you wanted.  If you don't want it to wrap , don't include the `% 9`.  Otherwise more examples are the best way to convey exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) v1.13.0 you can generate numbers in any radix (2..36).

It is handy to define the setting:

```
  "regexTextGen.predefined": {
    "Generate Number in radix": {
      "originalTextRegex": "(.*)",
      "generatorRegex": "{{=i+8:radix(16):size(6):ABC}}"
    }
  }
```

- Place cursors at the locations you want the numbers.
- execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression**
- select the **Generate Number in radix**
- press enter, modify the radix, size, ABC
- if you like the preview: <kbd>Enter</kbd>, otherwise <kbd>Esc</kbd>

If you want to have a step of 5 inbetween edit the generator expression in the input box to

```
{{=5*i+8:radix(16):size(6):ABC}}
```

In a following version you can specify the offset `{{i+8}}` in hexadecimal `{{i+0x10}}`

If you have to do this hexadecimal numbers a lot you can define a keybinding and set the properties, see README page for example.

Comment: @tahi in your `settings.json`

Comment: Many thanks. So I need to set these settings in settings.json file? If yes, I already did that. And seems like working fine. Not as flexible as atom editor but somewhat equally effective.

Comment: One one related question. What if I want to increment with a step of 2 or 3 or 5 etc? I have modified the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @tahi just multiply `i` with the step like `{{=5*i+8:radix(16):size(6):ABC}}`

Answer (score 0):

Using the extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) (disclaimer: I wrote it) this is pretty easy.  Use this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`

```
{
  "key": "alt+n",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    "replace": [
      "$${",
            
                                            // ${matchIndex} starts at 0
        "let result = ${matchIndex} + 8;",
        "return 'case_' + result.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').toUpperCase();",
      
      "}$$"
    ],
    
    "restrictFind": "line"
  },
}
```

[image: to hex demo]

If you want the hex numbers to start over at `08` no matter how many you select initially, use this `replace`:

```
  // with this version you just select the whole block and the numbers will run from 08 - 10 and start over at 08, see demo

{
  "key": "alt+n",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {

    "find": "(?<=case_)",  // added this to previous version

    "replace": [
      "$${",
            
      "let result = ${matchIndex} % 9 + 8;",      // added the '% 9' to wrap at 08
      "return result.toString(16).padStart(2,'0').toUpperCase();",
      
      "}$$"
    ],
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "selections"    // added this, find just in selections
  },
}
```

[image: to hex wrapping numbers at 08 demo]